# Sorting a list with 2 pieces of data alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

After sortting out one of my sorting functions which sorts by score now I need to get it to accurately sort it by the first letter of the first name

The data in the file looks like this:

```
Amber 0
Cyan 1
Blue 2
```

I tried this:

```
with open("Scores.txt","r") as f:
    lines = sorted(f.readlines())
    print lines
```

This gives it out in a weird order. It starts with names beginning with A then moves onto names with R, then O.

My output would need to be like this:

```
Amber 0
Blue 2
Cyan 1
```

It is a relatively simple program and I am using Python 2.7

Any help would be amazing I can also provide any info on my program!

Comment: That code looks right to me. Can you post a sample file that actually produces the problem?

Comment: _"It starts with names beginning with A then moves onto names with R, then O."_ and where in your example file are the names beginning with R and O?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
with open("Scores.txt","r") as f:
    lists = [line.rstrip().split() for line in f.readlines()]
    lists.sort()
    print(lists)

# Output
[['Amber', '0'], ['Blue', '2'], ['Cyan', '1']]
```

Comment: It's supposed to be sorted by the name first, so leave out the key.

Comment: If you are creating the list anyway why not use the `.sort()` method to save the creation of an extra list?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, thx for kind reminder. just updated my answer.